Enable all snapping types in QGIS using Python
Using the toolbar GUI of QGIS (Currenly using v3.28), I can enabled multiple/all the snapping types like this:

Now that's exactly what I'm trying to do in this code: (Just setting 2 types for the example)
snapping_config = QgsSnappingConfig() 
snapping_config.setEnabled(True)
snapping_config.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.AllLayers)

# This only enables Area Snapping
snapping_config.setTypeFlag(QgsSnappingConfig.AreaFlag)

# Using the same method again with different type, only overwrites the previously set type.
snapping_config.setTypeFlag(QgsSnappingConfig.CentroidFlag)

QgsProject.instance().setSnappingConfig(snapping_config)

But I can't figure it out since the setTypeFlag method only accepts only one SnappingType enum object.
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-3_38/src/core/qgssnappingconfig.h#L255
How can I do that in QGIS python?

You can set multiple Types using Qgis.SnappingTypes:
snapping_config.setTypeFlag(Qgis.SnappingTypes(Qgis.SnappingType.Vertex | Qgis.SnappingType.CentroidFlag | Qgis.SnappingType.Area))

You can find all SnappingType Enums in the documentation:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.38/core/Qgis.html#qgis.core.Qgis.SnappingType

That works! I can't seem to figure out how you found out the SnappingType.Vertex enum, I was using it as with the Flag word: SnappingType.VertexFlag
